# Which to choose Python or java

Tags: java, python

I have opportunity to study either JAVA or PYTHON.

But I can't decide which to choose. I am already well versed with C++.

Can you plz tell which one is better with our experience.

Comment: I think your question will be closed; that being said, if you plan to work professionally with it, Java's the better (and longer to learn) choice.

Comment: Where are the mods when needed? This question should have been closed ages ago! Edit: here they are! :)

Answer (score 3):

I'd say go for python.
Its very easy to code.

Answer (score 2):

This is a really relative questions and there is no "right" answer.

I personally would go with Python but I already took multiple Java classes. Python is fun and interesting but Java has been around for a while and isn't going anywhere any time soon.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just learning object oriented programming language then I will suggest you to start with JAVA. Because if you don't understand the ideas behind the object oriented programming nicely, you will certainly legging behind. but if you have good experience on the ideologies (i.e. structured programming language or object oriented) then, its not a matter whether you should go with JAVA or Python. The basic concept is the main thing you need to learn.

Answer (score 1):

I feel, there is not much about the language. Its just implementing the logic. You can use anything to express that. But the have to keep in mind about the drivers and libraries available for the language that you are selecting

Answer (score 1):

Start out with Python; use Python for your own hackish projects - it's great for Web Apps and rapid prototyping.

Learn Java later on and you'll enjoy it; learn it before Python and you won't appreciate the kind of OOP Java has to offer as much.

This is from personal experience; again, like twodayslate mentioned, there is no "right" answer. I learnt both Python and Java on my own and use mainly Python for personal projects.